# Find positions of objects on the noisy image

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have a bunch of images and I need to determine positions of crosses for further transformation of the image and the alignment procedure. The problem is that images are quite noisy and I'm new to all these things of computer vision. Generally, I'm trying to solve the task via opencv and python. I have tried several approaches described in the tutorial of opencv library but I did not get the appropriate result.

Consider: [image: a grayscale image with 4 crosses]I need to determine the exact positions of centers of the crosses (which I can do with about pixel accuracy by hand). The best result I have obtained via `findContours` function. I have adopted [code from the tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html) and I got:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

random.seed(42)

img = cv.imread("sample.png")
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_gray = cv.blur(img_gray, (3,3))

threshold = 150

dst = cv.Canny(img_gray, threshold, threshold * 2)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(dst, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

result = np.zeros((dst.shape[0], dst.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(len(contours)):
    color = (random.randint(0, 256), random.randint(0, 256), random.randint(0, 256))
    cv.drawContours(result, contours, i, color, 2, cv.LINE_8, hierarchy, 0)

cv.imwrite("result.png", result)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(10, 10);
ax.imshow(result, interpolation='none', cmap='gray');
```

which results in: [image: image with several contours found] Now I'm confused with the following steps. How can I define which contour is cross and which is not? What to do with crosses consisting of multiple contours?

Any help is really appreated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way on which you can determine what is a cross and what isn't is by making a bouning box `x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)` over each contour and selecting those that have h (height) and w (weight) bigger than treshold you provide. If you observe the noises on the image arent as big as the crosses.

I have also made an example on how I would try to tackle such a task. You can try denoising the image by performing histogram equalization followed by thresholding with OTSU threshold and performing an opening to the threshold (erosion followed by dilation). Then you can filter out crosses with height and weight of the contour and then calculate the middle points of every bounding box of the contours that is in the mentioned criteria. Hope it helps a bit. Cheers!

Example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('croses.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
equ = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(equ,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel, iterations = 2)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(opening,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for cnt in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    if w > 40 and h > 40:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        cv2.circle(img,(int(x+(w/2)), int(y+(h/2))),3,(0,0,255),-1)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly! I'll try to figure out what is happening here. Thank you!
Btw, would you suggest to change the type of marker from cross to something else, better recognizable?

Comment: Do you make these crosses yourself? Maybe you could draw rectangles?...you could make the criteria for sorting cv2.contourArea() and find the center with cv2.moments()? Cant really give a good idea since I dont know the exact application of this task.

Comment: Yes, I make crosses by myself. Previously, when I did this task by hand (I mean a search of centers of crosses), crosses were really nice - they have small features, that's why I was able to find centers quite accurately. I think rectangles are worse than crosses. I thought of something more complicated and use of template matching algorithm rather than bounding box. Crosses are fabricated via e-beam lithography if this somehow can help you.

Comment: You can ofcorse try template matching but it is more work and in my experience (maybe others have better) does not give as good of result as pure mathematical concept alghorithms. I think a better approach would be feature matching if you would like more complicated way. But my view on problems is that if "simple" works dont complicate. You could try making an X instead of +. This way you will get better bounding box if one of the X "leg" is shorter. You could however improve the search of the exact crossing instead of calculating it;)